# React native/navigation error displaying component/component is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I was a little bored of react-js recently and wanted to try react native, I followed a tutorial on youtube which used react navigation, and I got an error at the very beggining of creating my app (while creating my first component actually)

- First I got an error saying `Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.` but my string was in a text component
- Then I tried doing a component which just return en empty `<View></View>` but got an error  :

`` variant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function (received `undefined`) `` 
I concluded the error was coming from the component itself and not the text

- Finaly I saw on a forum it could comme from a bad import, even if I was sure it was imported correctly I tried declaring my component inside my app.js so no import would be required, but the same errors happen

Here is my code :

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { View } from "react-native-web";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </View>
  );
};


const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In the tutorial I was following the guy used react navigation 6 but called the function createStackNavigator()

In the official documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation they use `createNativeStackNavigator` instead of `createStackNavigator` (which is for v5), I tried deleting my node modules, installing the correct npm package, verified the versions, and then followed this documentation but I still get the same errors

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `createNativeStackNavigator` instead, and you also need to import `Text` since you only have `View`. Be sure to import React Native components from 'react-native' instead of 'react-native-web'. Doing all of this fixed your issue and I can now see the text displayed:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Actually I cleaned the code before posting it here and mistakenly remove the text import but it was imported on my project. The error came from importing from 'react-native-web' instead of 'react-native'